# How to order/sort a 2D table of dependencies

Tags: python, c, algorithm, sorting

I'm curious if there is some higher level theory/approaches/algorithm to solving this problem I have.

I'm working on a network routing problem (a proprietary radio network). By way of example, I have a network of 5 devices. For each device, I can measure how well it can hear other devices. The 0th root node is interesting only as a source. So in table form, I might end up with something like:

```
    _0_ _1_ _2_ _3_ _4_
1 | 21   -  42  55   0
2 |  0  63   -  18  20
3 | 20   0   0   -   0
4 |  0   0  13   0   -
```

Each row indicates how well that device can hear the other 5 sources. What I want to do is sort them so that each device gets the best sum signals from preceding elements. So for this simple case, the ordering might be `1, 3, 2, 4`. But it could just as well be `3, 1, 2, 4`. In fact, this second would be better because 1 can hear both 0 and 3. `3, 2, 1, 4` would work as well.

I'm trying to determine what kind of algorithm I can use to order these. There's a bit of traveling salesmen to it, and I don't need a "best" sort. Just a probably pretty good sort. I need to scale up to 9 devices with 10 sources.

Any thoughts, help, nudges, tips, hints appreciated.

Comment: If this is only 10 elements, why not brute-force it? I.e. calculate all paths?

Answer (score 4):

This problem can be modeled as a [minimum feedback arc set problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_arc_set), which is a NP-hard problem. The original graph is a complete directed graph, with the weight of each edge `(v0, v1)` being the signal strength from `v0` to `v1`. After computing maximum feedback arc set, do a topological sort will give an ordering that has the maximum total signal.